# Node.JS Forked Pipe

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to fork a node.js module as a child process per the example posted on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371113/how-can-i-execute-a-node-js-module-as-a-child-process-of-a-node-js-program).  The fork itself works, but the problem I am running into is that node is attempting to add the `.on('data')` and `.on('exit')` before the `fork('./DaemonSerial.js'` populates `tChild`

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;

// Start Serial Daemon/s
var tChild = fork('./DaemonSerial.js', [], {
  stdio: 'pipe'
});
tChild.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
  // output from the child process
  console.log("./DaemonSerial.js >>> " + data)
 });
EdgeMaster.Children[tChild.pid] = tChild;
tChild.on('exit', function(d) {
    console.log("./DaemonSerial.js >>> "+ tChild.pid + ' Exited:'+ d);
    delete EdgeMaster.Children[tChild.pid]
 });
```

I have also run into this problem elsewhere, and am reasonable sure there should be a method of enforcing a `do THIS then THAT` type of functionality even when the function itself does not have a callback. `child_process.fork(modulePath, [args], [options])` on [nodejs.org/api/child_process.html](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) does not list a callback.

ideas?

EDIT:
  I wrote a new script `forktest.js` to rule out any possibility that other parts of my script might be causing the issue. `forktest.js` is exactly as follows:

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;

var ForkDict = {};

function forkit(aPath){
    tChild = fork( aPath, [], {stdio: 'pipe'});
    ForkDict[tChild.pid] = tChild;
    ForkDict[tChild.pid].path = aPath;
    tChild.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        // output from the child process
        console.log( this.path +'>>> '+ data);
     }.bind(this));
    tChild.on('exit', function(d) {
        console.log( this.path +'>>> Exited:'+ d);
        delete ForkDict[tChild.pid]
     }.bind(this));
}

forkit('./DaemonSerial.js');
```

the error from the console reads as follows:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node forktest.js

/home/pi/forktest.js:9
    tChild.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of null
    at forkit (/home/pi/forktest.js:9:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/forktest.js:19:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Comment: According to the documentation it doesn't really look async, and I've only ever spawned new processes, but I've never had any issues with this. It does say in the docs that forking could take up to 30ms, and if there's no callback I guess you have to fake one with an interval that checks if it's ready etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fork` is asynchronous, but its return value is not populated asynchronously. It returns an instance of ChildProcess, that inherits from EventEmitter. An EventEmitter is commonly used for asynchronous tasks, but you receive events when something happens instead of using a callback. Like it says in the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation):

> These methods follow the common async programming patterns (accepting a callback or returning an EventEmitter).

In the first example:

- `fork` does not have a `stdio` option. You should probably use `silent: true` instead; which calls `spawn` with the `stdio` option set to "pipe".
- You try to read from a writable stream (stdin): `tChild.stdin.on('data', ...` You probably want to use `stdout`.

It appears that `stdin` and `stdout` can be `null` depending on if you use `silent: true` or not.  See `options.silent` in the docs for `fork`:

> `Boolean` If true, stdin, stdout, and stderr of the child will be piped to the parent, otherwise they will be inherited from the parent, see the "pipe" and "inherit" options for spawn()'s stdio for more details (default is `false`)

So the data is just going to your main script's `stdout`.  You can fix this with (note that your `stdio` option wasn't doing anything):

```
tChild = fork( aPath, [], {silent: true});
```

As I said earlier, you'll need to listen to the `data` event on `stdout`.

Comment: updated question to show exactly what I am observing.

Comment: Nodejs docs say that .stdin and .stdout are both `Stream object` doc lists `Stream object` as having `Event: 'data'`

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction What docs are you looking at?  `stdin` is a `Writable Stream`, which does not have a `data` event, as that wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction Updated with the full solution.  I'm still wondering what docs you're reading, since they don't appear to be correct (with regards to `stdin`/`stdout` and the `stdio` option to fork).

Comment: I have yet to find a solution.  dim'ed it out set a TODO and moved on.  The docs im looking at are http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin you are correct that stdin is `Writable Stream` but stdout is `Readable Stream` and according to http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html `Readable Stream` has a `Event: 'data'`

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction What goes wrong when you try what I suggested in my edit?

Comment: Missed your edit.  It works now, thank you.  I was under the impression that `{stdio: 'pipe'}` should do what `{silent: true}` actually does.  Thanks again.