# Nodejs execute node file and get its output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node.js and making a webserver, and what I would like to do, is to `require()` a file that executes nodejs code and capture that output of the file into a variable. is that possible?

I have the following:

**Main.js**

```
// Webserver code above
require('my_file.js');
// Webserver code below
```

**my_file.js**

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

I would like the output of **Main.js** to display `Hello World` in a web browser, it does display in the console when I go to the url, but what is actually displaying on the page is `console.log("Hello World");`

Is there any way I can get the browser to display just the `Hello World` and not the actual code?

**Edit**

When I do this:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response){
    // Stripped Code
    var child = require('child_process').fork(full_path, [], []);
    child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        response.write(data);
    });
    // Stripped Code
}).listen(port, '162.243.218.214');
```

I get the following error:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of null
    at /home/rnaddy/example.js:25:38
    at fs.js:268:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Am I not doing this correctly?

Comment: Have a look at the [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module, especially [`fork()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options). The [`stdout`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout) of a child process can be [streamed](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) to an open [`http.ServerResponse`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

Comment: Okay so I was able to fork() it, but I am not sure how to get the stream... If you see my edit, is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275556/node-js-forked-pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go! I got it!

```
var child = require('child_process').fork(full_path, [], {silent: true});
child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    response.write(data);
});
child.stdout.on('end', function(){
    response.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching things the wrong way. If your end goal is to write something to a browser, you shouldn't be using console.log at all. All you would need in `my_file.js` is `module.exports = 'Hello World';`

This isn't PHP where you would write things out in a file, then include that file to include it in the output to the browser.

## main.js

```
var http = require('http');
var content = require('./my_file.js');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.end(content);
}).listen(port);
```

## my_file.js

```
var content = '';
// build content here
module.exports = content;
```