# Restart node childprocess with changed files

Tags: node.js

Im forking my nodejs process into 4 child-processes.
One of this child-processes is for testing purposes The others are production.

Is there a way to restart the child-process with taking the changed files into account without having to restart the whole nodeprocess?

Comment: You cannot just kill your spawned process and then restart it? It should use the latest files then..

Comment: @AntonHarald is that so? tbh i didnt tried yet, because it seemed illogical to me

Comment: I didn't try it. But I'm quite sure - if I understand your problem correctly. Forking seems to be like spawning, just better suited for nodejs processes in particular. So if I do var cp = require("child_process"); var a = cp.spawn("myapp"); a.on('data'.... ; a.kill();  then, change the code of myapp and do the same thing for var b, I should get the latest version of myapp running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a detailed description how to communicate with forked node-js processes from within a node process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371113/how-can-i-execute-a-node-js-module-as-a-child-process-of-a-node-js-program).

The question was, if code-changes in a forked process are taken in account, when the fork is restarted. Yes they are.

once you start a new fork via

```
var sub = require("child_process").fork("my_module.js");
```

the current code is read from the actual file. You can stop the fork via sub.disconnect() and reload it again.