# node js child fork crashing parent on exception

Tags: node.js, fork

Im have a parent node which forking process like so :

```
 var cp = require('child_process').fork('./p1.js');
```

Everything is working great until child crash with some exception and kills the parent as well.

what am i doing wrong ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can checkout this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371113/how-can-i-execute-a-node-js-module-as-a-child-process-of-a-node-js-program Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think it's line 16 of `p1.js`.

Seriously, you need to see what exception it is, where it happens in the code, when it happens in time, what can be causing it and then fix the problem. This is the standard procedure. With no code example or even a description of the exception no one will be able to tell you anything more specific.